# using local storage in HTML5 can I share it between various users

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm planning to use html5 capability of localstorage to write a simple application, I would like to share the database file across multiple browsers(users on various machines) I'm not too worried about locking etc, as the number of users are only 3-5. Could anybody help on how i could achieve this.

Comment: That cannot be done using local storage.

Answer (score 1):

The is not possible as the data is stored on a per browser database. If your user switched between say Chrome and FF, a differing database would be used. The data is however shared amongst windows within the browser.